# Launch the REPL from within my app

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Suppose that I have implemented a few functions for some personal calculation at work. I'd like to build a `.jar` (uberjar) that my colleagues would use too in a REPL, like:

```
megacorpcalcs.core=> (+ 2 2)
4
megacorpcalcs.core=> (salary 8 0.4)
666$
```

What code should I type for a REPL to start when the `.jar` launches?

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: after your comments I've split this answer into 2

**1. Running your uberjar with a REPL**

Create your uberjar, and start it with:

```
java -cp /path/to/your/application-X.Y.Z-standalone.jar clojure.main -i @your_application/foo.clj -r
```

I had to add the `-i` parameter and point it to one of my clj files in order to get any of my classes in the project to actually load in the repl. There may be a better way to do this, but I haven't found it yet. Without it, you get a standard clojure repl but your application isn't loaded.

Note, you need the @ symbol so that it loads from the jar file relative to the classpath (i.e from root of jar).

This should start a repl which you can change namespace and run your application functions in.

Additionally, you can install `rlwrap` and prepend the java command with it so you can use history and arrow keys sanely.

**2. Embedding a REPL server in your application to connect to from another client**

You can embed your own repl on startup of your application (e.g. a simple main that just starts a repl instance), and then your users can run your jar file, and separately connect to it with their choice of tool (cider-jack-in, 'lein repl connect ...')

The simple version of this is:

```
(start-server :port 7890 :handler cider-nrepl-handler)
```

Substitute the port you want, see below for the appropriate namespaces to import.

Here is a more complete example:

```
(ns your-app.server
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [cider.nrepl :refer (cider-nrepl-handler)]
            [clojure.tools.nrepl.server :refer [start-server]]))

(def repl-server (atom nil))

(defn create-nrepl-server!
  [repl-port]
  (println (format "starting nrepl server on port %d" repl-port))
  (reset! repl-server (start-server :port repl-port :handler cider-nrepl-handler)))

(defn -main []
  ;;  ...
  (let [repl-port 7890]
    (create-nrepl-server! repl-port)
    (spit ".nrepl-port" repl-port)))
```

You'll need the following in your project.clj file

```
:plugins        [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0"]] ;; or whatever version you prefer
:dependencies   [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]]
```

Once connected to your custom repl, standard rules apply, just change namespace and call your functions.

Comment: Ouch, I thought there would be something more straightforward…

Comment: well you only need to run `(start-server :port 7888 :handler cider-nrepl-handler)` as an absolute minimum in your main method. The rest I took from my own code for sourcing environment values from configuration files.

Comment: OK I now understand your answer. I don't want users to connect from another app. I want them to just lauch the .jar (double click or CLI) and the REPL starts.

Comment: i wondered if this is what you really meant in your question. You might want to look at http://clojure.org/repl_and_main which describes running the main clojure.jar to invoke a repl, and you could try adding your jar on the classpath, which may work. I've not tried it though. I usually connect as described in my answer using nrepl.

Comment: @Gra I've update my answer, I managed to get my own uberjar working (without aot compilation), and starting a REPL (using clojure.main) with the application source loaded. I've left the previous answer as an alternate method, cut down to the basics